# Data Collection configuration file: config file must it be identical across all organizations?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Do all organizations need to use an identical collection configuration file?

I assumed that each organization could have its own collection configuration setup, so long as shared collections appear in the other relevant organization's configuration files.

However, [this page](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode_lifecycle.html?#step-three-approve-a-chaincode-definition-for-your-organization) states that the Collection Configuration needs to be consistent across all organizations.

[This page](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html) also explicitly states that "The collection file needs to be the same for all channel members."

If this is the case, then every single organization's collection config file must include the private collection definitions of every other organization with which it transacts?

Or is the intended meaning that there is at least one common collection definition within a config file that is the same across organizations?

(I started looking into this question as I am trying to debug a chaincode installation issue across a multi-org network where each org is a member of a shared (multi-member) and a private (single-member) collection.)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this discussion](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/message/9725) on the Hyperledger Fabric email list, and personal testing, the organizations do indeed need to use identical collection configuration files.